# How to paint the area under a normal curve in a histogram?

Tags: histogram

I have a histogram created from the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Generate some data for this demonstration.
data = norm.rvs(10.0, 2.5, size=2000)

# Fit a normal distribution to the data:
mu, std = norm.fit(data)

# Plot the histogram.
dat, bins_n, ignored = plt.hist(data, bins=30, density=True, edgecolor='black', alpha=0.6, color='gray')


for i in range(8,17):
    ignored[i].set_facecolor('g')

# Plot the PDF.
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
title = "Fit results: mu = %.2f,  std = %.2f" % (mu, std)
plt.title(title)
plt.show()
```

what I need is to paint only the section of the histogram that is below the curve (green color), but when trying it, I also paint the section that is outside the normal curve.

How could I do that?

[Normal distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuzBu.png)